# How to check if RMI is running in any port or not?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I have couple of questions related to RMI. In our application there are multiple services and all these services having JMX configuration.We are using Jmanage as client. JMX port is configured in setenv.sh of each service.

`CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port`

But we havnt configured RMI port and that is why RMI is running in port 1099 by default. I confirmed the same by running lsof -i :1099 command in all services. I have got output saying rmiregistry is running on this port in all services except one. In that particular service I didnt get any output which means RMI is not running in that port. However, Jmanage runs in that service

Now my questions are :

1. Is there any way to check if RMI is running in any other port ? If so, how ?
2. As I said earlier that we are using JMX to run Jmanage. So, is `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` enough to run and use Jmanage ? dont we need RMI connector/port for it ? Wondering how Jmanange is working if RMI is disabled (if at all)

Could you please help ?

Tomcat Version : 8.0.30

JDK Version : 1.8

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'RMI is running in any other port'? RMI just consists of remote objects listening at, and possibly sharing, TCP ports. You can tell whether a TCP port is listening but you can't tell *what* is listening other than by trying to use it.

Comment: @user207421 By that I meant "is there any way to check in which port rmiregistry is listening". Actually I found that its not listening to any port. 
It will be helpful if you can provide the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70892696/not-able-to-disable-port-1099. Could you please have a look ?